# Autodesk Forge Manifest: Missing reference

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We are currently working on an autodesk-forge-rest-webservice-client, have uploaded multiple dwg-files into the A360-owned bucket using our implementation and have encountered the following issue:

There are two files "A.dwg" and "B.dwg" which aren't referencing any other dwg-files and another one "C.dwg" referencing both "A" and "B" using unc-paths. After uploading the first two files, we are doing the same with file "C" while referencing "A" and "B" using their respective VersionUrns.

We now have encountered a scenario where the manifest of file "C" holds the following warning:
*One reference was not uploaded so the drawing may not be fully displayed. - Please upload the composite design with the missing referenced file: {0} "B.dwg"*

Since our approach works in most cases we had a look at the files but couldn't find anything suspicious which makes us wonder how to fix this issues. Has anyone else encountered a similar problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: Files "A" and "B" both are referencing image-files which we haven't uploaded resulting in missing references. This shouldn't be a problem when "C" needs to reference the other two dwg-files though, should it?

Comment: Please bear with me checking the scenario: since you mentioned version urn, it means you are working with drawings in BIM360. Are you following the blog to setup the reference? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files

Comment: yes, image with A.dwg, B.dwg should not affect the reference of C with A/B. the warning indicates A/B is not uploaded, or the reference may have problem. While the first I would like to know how your built the referene

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Indeed, that blog entry is exactly what we used for setting up references between DWGs. So the payload for the initial version of "C" looks exactly as described in that post (exempt other file-, folder- and version-urns and "included > relationships > refs > data" holding two entries obviously).

Comment: Are there any updates on this topic? (One similarity we have found is that the issue seems to occurre when a plan is being referenced that works with the Grauss-Krüger-coordinate-system. Could that be the reason?)